# How to make a Typescript function auto-infer a callback param type based on the object passed to registering function

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

Basically I have a function `call` through which an object with a callback on it is registered. I need to store these for later. Problem is that I can't get the compiler (or linter for that matter) to understand that the first (and only) param of callback is the type of the object itself.

This is what I have tried so far.

[>> Playground Link <<](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIDUEYC5gN7HC8AXAngBwKbgMICGANsQEaEDGA1gCKFqEA8AKgHzgC84Sqf4lEuSrVY4ABQATBoTEsAlFw4A3APYBLSclQBfYNpQAzAK4A7SmnWrTAoazZSZc8ADICQijXqN7i3vxRpRgA6QVJPakdGeQBuA3A9eLDicX8AtBwAZzQxAHJcgBpwMHAAUQAnctVysTRM8QAmAGYAFgBWeXi+ZIixIMIlHgSu1BKWAAkASQBlVAA9BbnwTIALVWNiSXBCYzRVAFp1U0Mccu3M9BW8TFxwVUNLvFUyACscC3B1NFyL62D4nSdRIlSANeBpdDYPBEcIibzMdhcHgjFA9ERiKKycAKQZqTQA-R8EzmSzWWykVjgHAADwypkkFxhwi8MnsDn6cj8KPA-VCHhEmNiBKSQlS3Iy2TyhW5aJofRkgwQCWKEAqVTOdUaTQaDU6ARQYymsxQiyWq3Wm22uwORxOZ0IFzQV0ht3ujzur3eaE+31+pn+fEBcR0QA)

V1

```
{
    type CallbackData<T> = {
        callback: (data: T) => void
    }

    function call<T>(data: T & CallbackData<T>) {
        data.callback(data);
    }

    call({
        test: '', // Error: ts(2345)
        callback: data => { }
        // THIS   ^^^^ should auto-infer as the type of the object it's on.
    })
}
```

V2:

```
{
    type CallbackData<T> = {
        callback: (data: T) => void
    }

    function call<T extends CallbackData<T>>(data: T) {
        data.callback(data);
    }

    call({
        test: '',
        callback: data => { } // Error ts(2322)
        // THIS   ^^^^ should auto-infer as the type of the object it's on.
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to write this currently that works how you want; see [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599). There have been steady improvements to simultaneous generic type argument inference and contextual callback param inference, but some situations aren't supported. Workarounds are to split into multiple params like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzG41w) or to annotate your types manually (but then you get no inference).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXOE1W) approach will help you

Comment: Hey, thanks to both of you for your responses. Actually quite helpful to know my solution is not possible as of this moment, thanks. I implemented my solution with Filly's V2 solution. You're both legends, thanks again :)

Comment: @jcalz if you wouldn't mind writing an explanation, you seem to understand the issue quite well. I'll mark that as an answer.